# Debug android framework UI part

Tags: android, remote-debugging, android-framework

I want to debug android Lockscreen.
I have full source code.

What i have found is `Lockscreen.java`(extends LinearLayout) is placed under `frameworks\base\policy` folder i.e. part of framework.

What i have found on internet/stackoverflow is, how to debug android framework service from `system_process` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358735/android-framework-debugging-in-eclipse%22here%22)

or how to debug framework from app(basically attach framework source code).

But How to debug something which is written as part of android framework(UI part like lockscreen) and not a service?

My problem is i have neither application nor it is a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

Problem was eclipse was not detecting framework code as application.

So i was not able to add framework code from "add->project" option.

What i have done now is, i added any dummy androidManifest.xml in `policy`folder(eclipse detects only manifest file, not mk file, it seems).

So eclipse started to detect it as an application.

Now i started `debug configurations` and gave id of `system_process` and press debug and set the breakpoint.

it worked.